NestJS project wont resolve workspace dependency
I have an npm workspace setup as below
apps                    
node_modules            
packages                
tsconfig.json
global-teardown.ts      
package.json            
services

root package.json
{
  "name": "monorepo",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "author": "",
  "private": true,
  "license": "ISC",
  "workspaces": [
    "services/*",
    "packages/*",
    "apps/*"
  ]
...
}

Under services, I have services/loans-service which is of this structure
config          domain          jest.config.js  package.json    usecases
data.txt        infrastructure  loans-test      tsconfig.json   usecases.txt

Under apps, I have apps/api that has a dependency on loans-service, this is the package.json
{
  "name": "api",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "loans-service": "1.0.0"
    ...
  }
...
}

Now, when I run nest-api:dev, the project is compiled without errors but during runtime, I get this error
[4:41:59 AM] Starting compilation in watch mode...

[4:42:02 AM] Found 0 errors. Watching for file changes.

Error: Cannot find module 'loans-service/usecases/approveLoanRequest.usecase'
Require stack:
- /Users/.../apps/api/lib/src/loans2/loans2.controller.js
- /Users/.../apps/api/lib/src/app.module.js
- /Users/.../apps/api/lib/src/main.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1048:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:901:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1115:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:130:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/.../apps/api/lib/src/loans2/loans2.controller.js:25:38)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1241:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1295:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1091:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:938:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1115:19)

This is my root tsconfig
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2016",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "rootDir": ".",
    "baseUrl": ".",                     
    "types": ["reflect-metadata", "jest"],
    "outDir": "./lib",
    "esModuleInterop": true
  }
}

this is the apps/api tsconfig
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2016",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "baseUrl": ".",                      
    "rootDir": ".",                      
    "types": ["reflect-metadata", "jest"],
    "outDir": "./lib",
    "esModuleInterop": true
  }
}

